# Junit set local variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm using additional jar file in my spring boot project. The problem is that one of the methods I want to test is using method from that jar that returns a value, but also sets a value to variable that is posted to it.

```
String valueThatWillBeReturned;
int returnMessage = method(valueThatWillBeReturned);
```

I don't know why the method is write by that. I'm not the writer of that jar and I cant debug it, but it works like that. It will return int that will be stored in `int returnMessage`, and also will set `valueThatWillBeReturned` that is posted to it.
It's a problem for me to test it. I'm setting the value of `int returnMessage` by:

```
when(external.method(valueThatWillBeReturned).thenReturn(1);
```

But how should I set value of `String valueThatWillBeReturned`?
The main problem is that my code depends on `String valueThatWillBeReturned` that should be returned.

**After Edit**

I made the upper example more simpler, but will give you additional details. I'm using an external library ImageSDK.jar. It uses .dll or .so file depending on the operation system.

So by documentation I should have `int[] pnMatchTemplate2Index = new int[1];` to post to the method below.

```
int result = libSDK.UFM_Identify(hMatcherContainer[0],
                                 templateForIdentification,
                                 sizeOfTemplateForIdentification,
                                 templatesFromDBForIdentification,
                                 sizeOfEachTemplateFromDB,
                                 numberOfTemplatesForCompare,
                                 5000,
                                 pnMatchTemplate2Index);
```

What method returns is `int result` that stores the return status, but the method also sets `pnMatchTemplate2Index` where index of matched template is stored. After that I'm using `templates.get(pnMatchTemplate2Index[0])` to get information I need.

So in the end my method depends on that parameter to return value, and I dont know how to set it by Junit to test my method return.

Comment: something like 'any', or the value you pass during the execution of your test?

Comment: If You need to use this value in your logic inside of the method, you have to separate call of the external method and other logic. So it will allow you to mock your method which calls external method.

Comment: It doesnt matter if I post any() or anyString(). `String valueThatWillBeReturned` is  declared in my code as emty variable and will be populated with data when posted to `method(valueThatWillBeReturned)`. The problem is that my code depend on that returned value.

Comment: As `String` is immutable, `valueThatWillBeReturned` will always have the same value after a call to `method` as it had before.

Comment: Well in my case the jar itself have a handler that sends the data to dll file that is doing the job and returns value to variable that has been posted to id.

Comment: I will edit the question with more details so you can get better point of view.

Comment: How does the value get back to your code? Is there a second call? Then mock it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I changed the location of the `pnMatchTemplate2Index` variable from method to class variable.

**Service.class**

```
// Receives the index of matched template in the template array;
private int[] pnMatchTemplate2Index = new int[1];
```

Then in the test method I mocked it like oliver_t suggested.

**ServiceTest.class**

```
int [] mockResults = {0};
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(underTest,"pnMatchTemplate2Index", mockResults);
```

Where:

`underTest` is the class we are testing

`"pnMatcherTemplate2Index"` is the private variable we want to mock in the class we are testing

`mockResults` is the value we want to set for the private variable

That way I managed to use `pnMatchTemplate2Index` to get the index I want from my other method.